# Django: setting the foreignkey in a model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have models for an event and an attendee

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
```

I want to create a view for people to signup as attendees, but I want to define what event they are signing up for in the view. The attendee should not be able to choose the event. They can only enter their name.

I've created a model form:

```
class AttendeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendee
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

And I created a view:

```
class Signup(FormView):
    form_class = AttendeeForm
    template_name = 'event/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse('event_signup_success')

    def event(self):
        """
        For example, let's say I have the event here.
        What do I do with it?
        """
        return Event.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Trying to submit this form currently results in a error, since the Attendee does not have an event defined. I'm not sure how I should be setting the event in the view. I do not want to add the event to the form as a hidden field and then set it in the view using `get_initial` because then the user could possibly change it by modifying the POST data. What is the best way to set the event in a way that the user cannot change it (or see other events)?

Comment: You can use the technique [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you!